# check sequentially a column in R and add 1 or 0

Tags: r, if-statement

I would like to do in r something equivalent that I do in excel:

```
IF(B3-[@[lagged Date]]>2,1,0)
```

In fact, it is just the previous row. Writing pseudo language could be considered as follows:
`If(x-x_i>y,1,0)`

Any way to do it with an explanation, please?

I am struggling with the way to go back and iterate over a column and go through each row using r.

Comment: sthg like: `ifelse(diff(x) > y, 1, 0)`. Explanation: `?diff`;)

Comment: Please give a [mcve]!